# Print the value of i outside the for loop in java

Tags: java, for-loop

I am trying to print/get the value of loop variable i and use it in another method outside the for loop. How do I do that?

```
public void mousePressed() {  
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
      boxes[i].openIt();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to use it in openIt() or somewhere else?  Does it matter at which point in the loop execution you get j?

Comment: You can store the list of values inside the loop into a collection or array and then use it wherever needed.

Comment: You do not have `j` in you code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables declared in the `for` statement are in scope only in the `for` components and the following code block, see [JLS section 14.14.1.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.1.1), in particular:

```
for ( ForInit ; Expression ; ForUpdate ) Statement
```

> If the ForInit code is a local variable declaration, it is executed as
>   if it were a local variable declaration statement (§14.4) appearing in
>   a block.

If you want to have it available outside the `for`, you have to declare it in a scope that is active in the location you want to access it; e.g. just outside the `for` loop:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 1000; ++ i)
    ;
// i is accessible in this scope
System.out.println(i);
```

Alternatively, if it is more appropriate, you could declare a separate variable and store the value of interest in it:

```
int k = ...;
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++ i)
    if (condition) // for example
        k = i;
// k is accessible in this scope, i is not
System.out.println(k);
```

For a brief summary see [this page](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html), specifically the *Loop Scope* example at the end, which has an example that is exactly like your question.

Answer (score 3):

You can't, by definition the value of `j` is only available within this loop. But of course you could declare a variable outside this for loop and assign it to something within your loop. Exactly what value do you want it to be though? Since the value of your counter `j` at the end will always be the same.

Comment: except if there is a break inside the loop, or if the exit condition of the for loop is more complex than i < 1000.

Comment: Sure, but that's not part of this code. I think we'll need further information from the poster on what he actually wants to do before  thinking of special cases such as those.